# Remove the load bottom if all the rows are display it

Tags: php, ajax

I have a ajax load more script found it on Stack Overflow.

[Load more status from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21111605/load-more-status-from-database/27538976)

This works

But if all the results are shown how I remove this

```
if ($row_cnt > 20)
{
  echo '<div class="loadstatus">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="" class="comingsoon">
      klicka för att ladda flerstatusar                  
    </a>
  </div>';
}
```

To:

no more results are found.

Comment: remove what exactly  ?

Answer (score 2):

If all that you are doing is changing the wording, this should do it.

```
if ($row_cnt > 20) {
    echo '<div class="loadstatus">no more results are found.</div>';
}
```

If you are looking to show the above text if the row count is greater than 20, but less than 20 you want to show your text.  This is what you want.

```
if ($row_cnt > 20) {
    echo '<div class="loadstatus">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="" class="comingsoon"> klicka för att ladda flerstatusar </a>     </div>';
} else {
     echo 'no more results are found.';
}
```

Comment: No this is not what I mean.
If all results are loaded from the moreResults.php. Then remove the lines.

Because if everything is loaded the lines are stand.

Sorry for my bad english. I hope that you understand me what I mean

Comment: I see what you are saying.  $row_cnt is set by PHP on the page load, so that value doesn't change regardless of how many times you call the ajax file.  You are going to need to create a JQuery variable that is updated on the response from the AJAX call and use that to see if the returned row count is greater than 20.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after further explanation here's what you need to do.

IMO, you should remove the PHP code from the first page and add a counter to keep track of how many rows were returned in the last request.  You can then change your code calling moreResults.php to a function and have it load when the page loads, then each time .comingsoon is clicked, call that function again and again, etc...  The counter would decide if you needed to load more content.

Then you would want to change the moreResults.php page to only return the DB results via JSON format.

So, basically to get what you'd like to do will require about a 75% code redo (from the other stack overflow link you posted), it's not complicated and is probably well documented, just not something I will be able to rewrite for you right now.